# ZeroMQ Router Losing Messages

Tags: network-programming, zeromq

The scenario is as follows:

- 2 ZMQ_ROUTER sockets, A and B;
- A binds to an address and is assigned an identity;
- B binds to an address, is assigned an identity and also connects to A;
- They talk for a while, everything is fine;
- I intentionally close the B socket;
- The B socket is reopened, rebound and reconnected using all the same parameters, assigned the same identity as previously;
- B sends message to A;
- A is not seeing the message. I am, however, noticing B's message in tcpdump output (tcpdump is monitoring all traffic on A's port).

This leads me to believe that zmq for some reason drops B's second message. Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: try add a sleep before the second send ("B sends message to A;") (zmq connect is async)

Comment: `ROUTER` to `ROUTER` is a difficult scheme to implement in ZMQ; did you read up on http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#reliable-request-reply? It describes how to do it reliably.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the comments. I found out that apparently re-using socket identities was causing this weird behavior. When the disconnected socket reconnects with a different identity, the problem goes away